# How to write to parquet a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got a spark application but when I try to write the dataframe to parquet the folder is created successfully but there is no data inside the folder just a file called "_SUCCESS"

Here is my code:

```
def writeToParquet(dataFrame: DataFrame, path: String): Unit = {
    dataFrame.write.parquet(s"$path.parquet")
}
```

Comment: are you sure there is data in the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I make operations to the dataframe like count, show...

Comment: Have you tried another format? Does it produce the same output?

Comment: `_SUCCESS` means the job finished, so an empty folder means there wouldn't be any data

Comment: @RicardoRodriguez your dataframe is empty.

Comment: are you running this job in "yarn" or "local". This is a known issue when you save files in "local" mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:

Assuming "df" is the name of your data frame and "tab1" to be the name of the table you want to store it as.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("parquet").saveAsTable("tab1")
```

Note: the saveAsTable method saves the data table in your configured Hive metastore if that's what you're aiming for. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: If you need to save it as a file just change the last method to `save`: ```df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("parquet").save("tab1")```